# Chat and Feed app using getStream, having custom UI

Tags: android, ios, chat, feed, getstream-io

I want to integrate getStream to enable chat and feed in my next mobile app (Android and iOS both). I am struggling with the best possible solution with this implementation. The first query here is the connection:

1. The app should connect with getStream APIs to enable chat and feed
2. The app should call our server (written in NodeJS) and the server will transfer the call to getStream.

In case 1, the dev team is facing issue such as not getting response in JSON format and with case 2, the dev team is not able to subscribe channels/events.

Is it possible to implement chat and feed having my own custom UI and not the one provided by getStream for mobile apps?

If possible then please share the link of the resources validating your answers.

Answer (score 1):

> case 1, the dev team is facing issue such as not getting response
>   in JSON format
>   case 2, the dev team is not able to subscribe
>   channels/events.

Are you not getting any response or there are some errors? How do you subscribe to channels/events? Probably better to ask in a dedicated SO questions.

> Is it possible to implement chat and feed having my own custom UI and
>   not the one provided by getStream for mobile apps?

Yes, it is possible. There're clients without UI components, so you can implement your own UI:

Chat iOS client: https://cocoapods.org/pods/StreamChatClient
Chat Android client: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-android-client/
Feeds iOS client: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-swift
Feeds Android client: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-java